# Limit for the norm of Sequence spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

let $0 < p < 1$ and $\ell_p(\mathbb{R} )$ be the class space of all $p$-summable
real valued sequences. Notice that $\| x \|_p = ( \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} | x_j |^p )^{1/p} $ is not a norm.

Find $\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} \| x \|_p $. Argue your answer for the limit.

My approach is as follows:

When $0 < p < 1$ it is only a quasi-norm, it does not satisfy the triangle inequality but it induces a metric that is ‘concave’.

Notice that for $x_i \neq 0$:

$\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} | x_j |^p = 1$

and for $x_i =0$:

$\lim_{p \rightarrow 0} | x_j |^p = 0$

I don't know how to continue from here. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this question and what you've tried so far. In particular, do you have a hypothesis as to the correct answer? If so, then what part of the argument for its correctness is giving you trouble?

Comment: Interestingly, it is possible for a sequence $x$ satisfying $x \in \mathfrak L_p(\Bbb R)$ for all $p> 0$ to be such that $\lim_{p \to 0}\|x\|_p = \infty$.

Comment: Try  sequences with two nonzero terms

Comment: Thank you @RyszardSzwarc !

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have edited it. Thanks for your recommendations.